# Insertar valores de múltiples checkbox secuencialmente en la Base de Datos MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes chicos espero me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente, me disculpo de antemano por no poner un fiddle con una prueba replicable, si me dan una guía de como hacerlo actualizaría el post con gusto, todo para hacerlo lo más resumido posible.

Necesito que al tildar diferentes checkbox a la vez de una lista de productos, me almacene los valores de los codigos de barra de dichos productos en registros diferentes de la base de datos, por lo que la salida deseada sería así.

Tabla acsi_posprecios

```
ID | ID_LISTA | CODIGOBARRAS
1       1           0001
2       1           0002
```

El HTML sería una tabla con la lista de productos traída de la base de datos

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" name="frmActualizaPreciosLista" method="post" action="dist/rest/cnt_rest.php?opc=13&i=<?php echo $rowProducts["ID"][$j]; ?>">
   <table id="tablaDatosMain" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                DESC.CORTA
            </th>
            <th>
                PROD/SERV
            </th>
            <th>
                CÓD BARRAS
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
/// ESTA QUERY DEBE TRAERSE LOS PRODUCTOS, CON LOS CAMPOS SOLICITADOS PARA DESPUÉS PROCEDER A ACTUALIZARLOS EN LAS CORRESPONDIENTES TABLAS.
$sqlBuscaProductosTablaN = ""; // Aquí debe ir su query para traerse los productos
$resBuscaProductosTablaN = mysqli_query($link,$sqlBuscaProductosTablaN);
while($filaListaAmbasProdTablaN = mysqli_fetch_array($resBuscaProductosTablaN)){?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $filaListaAmbasProdTablaN["DESCRIPCION_CORTA"]; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $filaListaAmbasProdTablaN["PRODSERV"]; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $filaListaAmbasProdTablaN["CODIGOBARRAS"]; ?></td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="flat-red"  name="check_prod[]" value="<?php echo $filaListaAmbasProdTablaN["CODIGOBARRAS"];?>" id="editarPrecioPromocional">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php

            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>
                DESC.CORTA
            </th>
            <th>
                PROD/SERV
            </th>
            <th>
                CÓD BARRAS
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</form>
```

Y... el controlador para insertar los productos lo tengo así.

```
   //************************************************************************************************************************** OPC = 13
    if($opc == '13'){                                                                  
    //AGREGAR ITEM DE TABLA DE LISTA DE PROMOCIONES - PRODUCTOS Y PRECIOS DE DESCUENTO - VIGENCIA DE LAS LISTAS

        $idLista = $_GET['i'];
        $flag = true;
        $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $txtUser = $_SESSION['usuario'];
        $empresa = $_SESSION['empresa'];


         // ES ESTA PARTE DEL SCRIPT LA QUE NO HE PODIDO DESCIFRAR PARA HACER EL INSERT SECUENCIALMENTE :/
        $checkListaHasItems = $_POST["check_prod"][0];
        // $precio = $_POST['precio'][0];

        $sqlInserta = "INSERT INTO acsi_posprecios (ID_LISTA, CODIGOBARRAS, AUDIT_FECHA, AUDIT_USER, EMPRESA, ELIMINADO) 
                       VALUES ('".$idLista."',
                               '$checkListaHasItems',
                               '".$fecha."',
                               '".$txtUser."',
                                '".$empresa."',
                               '0'
                        )";
            $result = mysqli_query($link,$sqlInserta);

            $sqlModificaListas = "UPDATE acsi_poslistapromociones SET HAS_PROMO_PRICE_PRODUCTS = 1, AUDIT_USERMOD = '$txtUser', AUDIT_FECHAMOD = '$fecha' WHERE ID = ".$idLista;


            $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $sqlModificaListas);



            //Segunda Insert

            if (!$result) {
                $flag = false;
                $err = mysqli_error($link);
                header('Location: ../../p_cfgPriceList.php?opc=NOQUERY1&er='.$sql);
            }

            if (!$result2) {
                $flag = false;
                $err = mysqli_error($link);
                header('Location: ../../p_cfgPriceList.php?opc=NOQUERY2&er='.$err);
            }

            if ($flag) {
                mysqli_commit($link);

                addLog("MD - CONFIGURACIONES > LISTAS-PROMOCIONALES", "El usuario $_SESSION[nombre] modificó los datos de una Lista : $txtNombre");
                header('Location: ../../p_cfgPriceList.php?opc=OKact');

            } else {
                mysqli_rollback($link);

            } 




    }
```

Cualquier duda, correción o consejos estoy atento, gracias de antemano por su paciencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la respuesta... jajaja. abajo la adjunto con las instrucciones por sí alguien llega a tener un problema similar.

Primero hay que colocar un contador al array del checkbox en HTML e iniciar la variable al principio del while que itera los productos.

Comienzo del ciclo while:

```
 <?php while($rowProducts = mysqli_fetch_array($resBuscaTodo)){$j=0; $idP = 0;?>
<td>
   <div class="btn-group">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>

            <input type="checkbox" class="flat-red"  name="check_prod[<?php echo $idP; ?>]" value="<?php echo $filaListaAmbasProdTablaN["CODIGOBARRAS"];?>" id="editarPrecioPromocional">
         </label>

       </div>

    </div>
 </td>

</tr>


 <?php $idP++; ?>
<?php
 }
?>
```

Y en el controlador.... mediante un foreach le asignamos el name como key.

```
foreach($_POST['check_prod'] as $key => $product) {

            $productos = $_POST['check_prod'][$key];
            $sqlInserta = "INSERT INTO acsi_posprecios (ID_LISTA, CODIGOBARRAS, AUDIT_FECHA, AUDIT_USER, EMPRESA, ELIMINADO) 
                   VALUES ('".$idLista."',
                           '$productos',
                           '".$fecha."',
                           '".$txtUser."',
                            '".$empresa."',
                           '0'
                    )";
            $result = mysqli_query($link,$sqlInserta);
        }
```

Saludos amigos, disculpen la molestia.